# How to set up Nest.js debugger in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, docker, debugging, nestjs, webstorm

Can someone explain how to setup WebStorm debugger with nest.js? For now I setup like this:

[image]

But it does not work I am getting an error:

> Error Invalid command: `/tmp/b7a1c83c-0578-453b-b899-d094359ab244/backend-nest/src/main.ts`